# remote procedure calls from {Python | Ruby | ...} to C++

Tags: c++, sockets, http, client-server, rpc

**TL;DR:** Is there framework for making calls from a client process written in language X to a server process written in C++?  I don't mind if I use TCP/IP or UDP or HTTP to communicate between the processes.

**Details**:

I've coded up a real-time sound synthesizer written in C++.  Now I'd like to rewrite it as a server that takes high-level directives ("play note", "stop note" etc) from a separate client process.  Ideally, the client process could be written in any language, but I'm leaning towards Python or Ruby.

I've sketched out a way to handle the communication between client and server: The client could emit JSON over a pipe or socket to be received by the sound server.  The JSON would then be mapped into method calls on the server.  Simple.

This starts to look a lot like doing RPC (remote procedure calls), but as I've researched that, I can only find libraries for "*intra*-language" RPC (i.e. C++ client to C++ server).  The only reference for an *inter*-language RPC is the [Inter-Language Unification](ftp://ftp.parc.xerox.com/pub/ilu/ilu.html) project from Xerox PARC, but the last apparent activity there was in 2000.

Another option is to use RESTful HTTP (or `WebSockets`) to communicate with the sound server.  Is there such a thing as a lightweight C++ framework that I could use to create this?

**Note**: Extra credit for a system that works across multiple machines, not just localhost.

Answer (score 0):

(If SO gave badges for answering one's own questions, I would have racked up a bunch of them by now...)

A programmer friend who I think of as a "Green Beret of Programming" recommended Thrift and uses it extensively:

https://thrift.apache.org/

From the web page:

> The Apache Thrift software framework, for scalable cross-language services development, combines a software stack with a code generation engine to build services that work efficiently and seamlessly between C++, Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl, Haskell, C#, Cocoa, JavaScript, Node.js, Smalltalk, OCaml and Delphi and other languages.

It goes on to show an example of a single Thrift definition file that specifies RPC between a Java Server and a Python Client.  Just the sort of thing I was looking for!  (And I still have no idea why my Google searches failed me...)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is JSON-RPC: http://json-rpc.org/, or the updated version in http://www.jsonrpc.org

There are several libraries listed for many languages here, with varying amount of weight attached to each.

Comment: I like the simplicity of JSON-RPC (and I've taken the liberty of updating your answer with a pointer to the more recent version).  JSON-RPC doesn't allow you to write one definition file that works across multiple languages, which is why I'm leaning towards Thrift.